# Autofac: Register type where parameter is dependant on propertie of ApiController

Tags: c#, autofac

I want to register Repository with Autofac so that it is the same as in parameterless constructor? Which I then intend to remove.
Example code:

```
public class GroupController : ApiController
{
    protected IRepository Repository;
    protected ISettings Settings;

    protected GroupController()
    {
        Settings = new Settings();
        Repository = new Repository(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? Settings.ConfigAuth : Settings.Config)
    }

    public GroupController(ISettings settings, IRepository repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
        Settings = settings;
    }
}
```

This is an api controller in .Net framework.
Settings are written in web.config.
This is how autofac config looked like before I had only one config.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var settings = new Settings();
Builder.RegisterType<Repository>()
   .As<IRepository>()
   .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(RepoConfig), settings.Config))
   .InstancePerRequest();
```

There is currently only one implementation of IRepository.

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
   private readonly RepoConfig _config;

   public(RepoConfig config)
   {
      _config = config;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you wish to supply a specific implementation of `IRepository` to `GroupController`? What are the names of all of your `IRepository` implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented an workaround for this implementation. Not the best way but it works.
This way initialization of Repository doesn't need parameter and I set it with a propertie in constructor of Controller.

```
public class GroupController : ApiController
{
    protected IRepository Repository;
    protected ISettings Settings;

    public GroupController(ISettings settings, IRepository repository)
    {
        Settings = settings;
        Repository = repository;
        Repository.RepoConfig = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? Settings.ConfigAuth : Settings.Config
    }
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
   private readonly RepoConfig _config;

   public RepoConfig RepoConfig
   {
       get => _config;
       set
       {
           _config = value;
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

And for autofac there is standard DI refister:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
Builder.RegisterType<Repository>()
   .As<IRepository>()
   .InstancePerRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lambda Registrations. From Autofac documentation

> You can register components using lambda expressions and make a
>   runtime choice right in the registration for how to handle things.
>   Note this may have an effect on performance depending on the expense
>   of the runtime check and how often it gets executed, but it’s an
>   option.

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html (Check lambda expression components)

Based on your example using Lambda Registrations, you can do autofac reg as below (I have not tested)

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c => new Settings()).As<ISettings>();

        builder.Register<Repository>((c) =>
            {
                ISettings s = c.Resolve<ISettings>();
                Settings repoSettings = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? s.ConfigAuth : s.Config;
                return new Repository(repoSettings);
            }
        )
       .As<IRepository>()
       .InstancePerRequest();

        Container = builder.Build();
```

Then remove your parameter-less constructor and add

```
public GroupController(IRepository repository)
{
    Repository = repository;
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I already tried similar implementation, but the main problem is User, which is a property of ApiController and is only available in controller.

Comment: Its always good that If you have tried something, you should include it in your post at first, so others know what's your real problem is...  :)